# Python eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue

I have a 336x336 coinsurance matrix and I calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using numpy as follows with sorting.

```
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(cov)
idx = evals.argsort()   
evals = evals[idx] 
evecs = evecs[:,idx]
```

The problem is that the last value in evals is strange compared to other values.
Something like this:

```
    evals[:3]
    [ -6.11117191e-19  -6.11117191e-19  -1.08420217e-19]
    evals[-3:]
    [  4.29345466e-19   7.08196415e-19   1.69419875e-02]
```

The highest eigenvalue, 1.69419875e-02, is very high compared to other values. I have checked all the 336 eigenvalues and all except this one is more or less in same range.

Can anyone tell me why is this so.

Hi mrcl,
   Thank you for your reply. I have generated the 8x8 covariance matrix using precision suggested by you. It now looks like this:

```
[[  0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00]
  [  0.00e+00   4.62e-05   9.25e-05   4.62e-05   0.00e+00  -9.25e-05  -4.62e-05  -4.62e-05]
  [  0.00e+00   9.25e-05   1.85e-04   9.25e-05   0.00e+00  -1.85e-04  -9.25e-05  -9.25e-05]
  [  0.00e+00   4.62e-05   9.25e-05   4.62e-05   0.00e+00  -9.25e-05  -4.62e-05  -4.62e-05]
  [  0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00]
  [  0.00e+00  -9.25e-05  -1.85e-04  -9.25e-05   0.00e+00   1.85e-04   9.25e-05   9.25e-05]
  [  0.00e+00  -4.62e-05  -9.25e-05  -4.62e-05   0.00e+00   9.25e-05   4.62e-05   4.62e-05]
  [  0.00e+00  -4.62e-05  -9.25e-05  -4.62e-05   0.00e+00   9.25e-05   4.62e-05   4.62e-05]]
```

For column 1 and row 1, I am not sure why all is zero, I calculated manually also the covariance of these column and row and it is zero only, may be there is not much change in the original values, The original values are:

```
0.06  0.05  0.05  0.08  0.05  0.06  0.06  0.02

0.06  0.04  0.03  0.07  0.05  0.08  0.07  0.03
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is "coinsurance matrix"?

Comment: This is a math question not a programming question. I've flagged it and suggested it is moved to http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: also how does `np.diag(cov)` look like?

Comment: It could be that all but one of the eigenvalues are 0, and what you are seeing is numerical noise.  How is `cov` generated?

Answer (score 1):

It means all of your eigenvalues are zero, except one. I think your matrix may not be a full rank matrix.

Answer (score 0):

@newbie

Based on the 8x8 matrix I noticed a pattern of zero rows and columns which repeats every 
fourth column or row. Whenever a column or a row of a matrix is full with zeros, this makes the determinant to be zero and the matrix is singular, therefore your cov matrix has no inverse. In this case, the returned eigenvalues are the same as the singular values from the singular value decomposition(SVD).

I would recommend you to double check the reason why the calculation of your covariance matrix leads to rows and columns full of zeros, even in the main diagonal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I generated covariance matrix by calculating the frequency of di tri and tetra nucleotide word frequency in a sequence.

Comment: fo ex: seq = AATGCGTAGCGTGCAGTAGCAG'

Comment: and difreq = AA,AT etc tri = AAA,ATG etc and tetra = AAAA, TGAT etc. this way I generates frequency matrix and thereby covariance matrix. So, my covariance matrix is not so uniform.

Comment: Can you send an example with a matrix 10x10, you could copy and paste the results here. It would help someone to help you.

Comment: Hi mrcl! Here is the covraince matrix:

Comment: 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 4.622781065088757966e-05 9.245562130177515932e-05 4.622781065088761354e-05 0.000000000000000000e+00 -9.245562130177515932e-05 -4.622781065088754578e-05 -4.622781065088757966e-05

Comment: 0.000000000000000000e+00 9.245562130177515932e-05 1.849112426035503186e-04 9.245562130177522708e-05 0.000000000000000000e+00 -1.849112426035503186e-04 -9.245562130177509155e-05 -9.245562130177515932e-05
0.000000000000000000e+00 4.622781065088761354e-05 9.245562130177522708e-05 4.622781065088764742e-05 0.000000000000000000e+00 -9.245562130177522708e-05 -4.622781065088757966e-05 -4.622781065088761354e-05

Comment: I am not able to copy paste the whole matrix here, as it is not allowing me to do. I created 8x8 matrix and only the first 4 rows are here.

Comment: @newbie you can edit your post and include this information there. To make it less cluttered you can set the precision of your printed values by using the command `np.set_printoptions(precision=2,linewidth=150)`. This will adjust the number of decimals of the printed float values to 2 and make the usable line width bigger in this case 150 characters. I had a look in your printed values and noticed that the values of your first column and row are all equal to zero. Any reason for that?